# Adding lines to a linux file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to add lines `'{"index":{"_id":$number_of_id}}'` to my file name ss.josn before each json object (which is a line)

cat ss.json

input example:

```json
{"msisdn":"255742005249","subscription_date":"2021-05-26T16:41:40.467Z","optout_date":"2022-01-03T19:12:59.808Z","total_charged_amount":1300}
{"msisdn":"255742009077","subscription_date":"2019-12-31T22:00:00.000Z","optout_date":"2022-01-09T14:08:00.282Z","total_charged_amount":3370}
{"msisdn":"255742009703","subscription_date":"2019-12-31T22:00:00.000Z","optout_date":"2022-01-01T12:34:02.104Z","total_charged_amount":400}
```

Desired output:

```json
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"msisdn":"255742005249","subscription_date":"2021-05-26T16:41:40.467Z","optout_date":"2022-01-03T19:12:59.808Z","total_charged_amount":1300}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"msisdn":"255742009077","subscription_date":"2019-12-31T22:00:00.000Z","optout_date":"2022-01-09T14:08:00.282Z","total_charged_amount":3370}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"msisdn":"255742009703","subscription_date":"2019-12-31T22:00:00.000Z","optout_date":"2022-01-01T12:34:02.104Z","total_charged_amount":400}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JiříBaum trying to do for loop to insert the desired line before each json object

Comment: Do not use Bash to manipulate JSON. Use JQ instead: `jq -s 'to_entries[] | {"index":{"_id":(.key+1)}},.value'`

Comment: My comment that question closing feels like inquisition got lost somehow. I have to add it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that each line is a json struct and you don't have multiline case, a script like this should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

_id=0
while read -r line; do
 echo "{"index":{"_id":$_id}}" >> result.json
 echo $line >> result.json

 _id=$((_id+1))
done < ss.json
```

Maybe not the most elegant option, but you will have a **result.json** file with your desired output.